# How to clean up an oil spill on a foam floor?

Tags: cleaning

I have a small section of my office, the kitchen specifically having foam flooring and I spilled some hot sauce that had oils, and since tried many household cleaning products to get it out, but it's been no use. I tried using floor cleaners, and dishwashing liquids, cif and water stain cleaner. Is vacumming a way to get it out?  Can the community help me out? [image: oil spilled on floor]

Comment: Can you describe the foam flooring more? I am picturing simple Styrofoam, but I have never seen that used as flooring.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Normal vinyl floor tiles have a foam backing under the printed surface for some shock absorbing ability to deaden sound by stopping the conduction through a rigid support.

Comment: Hi Rajath, Welcome to Lifehacks.stackexchange. Please tell us what you have tried with a bit more detail so we don't suggest things that have failed. There's a chance that the materials you tried may have worked partially and need be repeated to be more successful. Repeated attempts may dilute the oil enough to be acceptable.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question with a photo. Please let me know if you can help, it's about 2 days old now

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if there's turmeric and saffron in the mix?

If you used some liquid (dishwashing) detergent already to cut/dilute/remove the oil, then some water soluble stuff like bleach may remove the colourful pigment.

Check to see if all the oil has been dissolved and removed by putting some water on the stain to see if it forms droplets, (there's still oil preventing the water from a smooth sheeting coat) you must continue to use a drop or two more of detergent and rinsing clean until the oil base of the sauce is gone.

Now, water soluble cleaners can work where the oil base previously protected the stain.

When the oil is removed, soak a cotton wool ball or paper towel in hydrogen peroxide and let it sit on the stain for a few minutes or more. You won't overdo it. There's no need to scrub. The reaction is chemical not physical. Repeat a few more times if it appears to be working.

No? You can try a few drops of chlorine bleach and rinse after a minute or two. If the stain looks lighter, repeat.

Be patient and after a couple of treatments it should look better.
Hydrogen Peroxide is a kind of bleach which has no odour; but, is not so aggressive as chlorine bleach.

Read the warning labels on any materials you use and under no circumstances mix any individual cleaning solutions as the reaction can be unpredictable and produce toxic or dangerous results.

Good luck

Comment: I'm not sure of the turmeric and saffron in the mix. It's a hot sauce spill, and they might have used it, but it's mostly chili oil.  THe sirface of the floor is quite hydrophobic and so, it's hard to make out what you said. I'll try the bleach method and see. Thank you